# UILocalNotification's alertTitle property doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

`UILocalNotification` has an `alertTitle` property but it doesn't work. Whatever title you give to a notification, it shows my apps name instead. If you check iCalendar's event alert, they are not showing app's name.

**P.S:** It has nothing to do with UIAlertView, because I am talking about it effect in background state.

Comment: It will work from iOS version 8.2.

Comment: I am using iOS version 9, it isn't changing.

Comment: Title strings should be short, usually only a couple of words describing the reason for the notification.

Comment: @KathiravanG, I tried differnt short strings, but with no gain. I guess Apple doesn't allow apps to change the title. It may be because, if every app starts changing the title for their alerts in background then a user won't be able to distinguish between alerts that is why the title seems to be reserved for App's name.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked it with `Xcode 7` and `Swift 2` and it is working for me:

Following is my code in `ViewController` file for initialization and assign properties to `UILocalNotification()`

```
   let localNoti : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
   localNoti.fireDate = //fireDate
   localNoti.alertTitle = //Your title will goes here
   localNoti.alertBody = "alert body for local notification"


  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNoti)
```

At the same time in `AppDelegate.swift`, i was written following code:

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification){
    let state: UIApplicationState = application.applicationState
    if state == UIApplicationState.Active{

       // Here i have created an AlertView to display local notification, Which will give title to LocalNotification

    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: notification.alertTitle, message: notification.alertBody, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alertView.show()
   }
 }
```

I hope above information will work for you.

[image]
In image -> "Reminder" is Title of my LocalNotification and notification body is "Message Body"

Comment: If the app is in background state, then didReceiveLocalNotification won't be called. And we are unable to change the title. Try doing it when app is in background state.